# Problems setting TL-WN951N (AR5416/AR5008) into Master mode

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, debian-wheezy, hostapd

I recently bought a TL-WN951N PCI card, it gets detected right and the module being used is ath9k.

When trying to set it to master mode however, it prints:

```
$ iwconfig int1 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device int1 ; Invalid argument.
```

OS (from `uname -a`): `Linux foo 3.2.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Mon Jul 23 03:50:34 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`

Anybody knows why?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, just post an actual answer and accept it as the working solution later. Please don't put any solutions into your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently newer wireless-tools requires `hostapd` in order to set an wireless extension in Master mode. They also deny manual setting of the Master mode for some reason.

So I guess it's "Solved"